# Why is my html code not calling on my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still learning javascript, HTML, and CSS, but I'm trying to build a game. When the HTML runs it's supposed to call the javascript to make the images move, but it won't connect to it at all.

I tried to use alert boxes at the beginning of the code, but they don't run and I don't get any error messages. I have also looked through everything that I think could cause this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="MissileSurvivalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body  onload="setInterval(movePlayer, 10),  setInterval(PressRightFuction, 25), setInterval(PressLeftFuction, 25), setInterval(ObjectCollisionFunction,10), setInterval(MissileMoveFunction, 10), setInterval(Timer,1000);"  bgcolor = "DDDDDD" background="Grass.jpg">


<img id="PlayerTank" src="BlueTank.png" alt=""  width="50" height="50" Lo = "10" >


<img id="Wall1" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall2" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall3" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall4" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall5" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall6" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall7" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall8" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall9" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">
<img id="Wall10" alt = "" width = "50" Height "50" Lo = "10">

<img id="Missile1" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile2" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile3" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile4" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile5" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile6" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile7" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile8" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">
<img id="Missile9" src="Missile2.png" alt="" width = "30" height="50" Lo="10">

<img id="buttonBack" src ="ColorBack.jpg" alt ="" width = "200" height = "80" Lo="10" >

<button id="btnUp" type="button"  on-tap="mouseDown" on-release="mouseup">Up  </button>
<button id="btnDown" type="button"  on-tap="mouseDown" on-release="mouseup">Down  </button>
<button id="btnLeft" type="button"  on-tap="mouseDown" on-release="mouseup">Left  </button>
<button id="btnRight" type="button"  on-tap="mouseDown"  on-release="mouseup">Right  </button>

    <script src="MissileSurvivalScript.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
alert("CONNECTED");
alert("In this game the player is trying to survive the missile attack for as long as possible.");

//Objects
var picPlayer = document.getElementById("PlayerTank");
var btnDown = document.querySelector("#btnDown");
var btnUp = document.querySelector("#btnUp");
var btnRight = document.querySelector("#btnRight");
var btnLeft = document.querySelector("#btnLeft");
  //Walls{
var picWall1 = document.getElementById("Wall1");
var picWall2 = document.getElementById("Wall2");
var picWall3 = document.getElementById("Wall3");
var picWall4 = document.getElementById("Wall4");
var picWall5 = document.getElementById("Wall5");
var picWall6 = document.getElementById("Wall6");
var picWall7 = document.getElementById("Wall7");
var picWall8 = document.getElementById("Wall8");
var picWall9 = document.getElementById("Wall9");
var picWall10 = document.getElementById("Wall10");
  //}
  //Missiles{
var picMissile1 = document.getElementById("Missile1");
var picMissile2 = document.getElementById("Missile2");
var picMissile3 = document.getElementById("Missile3");
var picMissile4 = document.getElementById("Missile4");
var picMissile5 = document.getElementById("Missile5");
var picMissile6 = document.getElementById("Missile6");
var picMissile7 = document.getElementById("Missile7");
var picMissile8 = document.getElementById("Missile8");
var picMissile9 = document.getElementById("Missile9");
  //}


//Varibles
var dblplayertop = 300.0;
var dblplayerleft = 200.0;
var dblSpeed = 0.0;
var dblangle = 0.0;
var blnSpinR = false;
var blnSpinL = false;
var blnGoForward = false;
var blnGoBack = false;
var dblMathAngle = 90;
var blnPlayerMove = true;
var intTime = 0;
var blnEnd = false;
  var dblLeftSpeed = 0.0;
  var dblTopSpeed = 0.0;

//Buttons ------------------------------------------------------

btnUp.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownU);
btnDown.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownD);
btnRight.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownR);
btnLeft.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownL);
btnUp.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpU);
btnDown.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpD);
btnRight.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpR);
btnLeft.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpL);


//Fuctions -------------------------------------------------------
 function PressRightFuction(){
   if (blnSpinR == true){
        dblangle += 1;
   document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.transform = "rotate(" + dblangle + "deg)";
   dblMathAngle--;
   if (dblMathAngle == -1)
     dblMathAngle = 359;

   }

 }

function PressLeftFuction(){
  if (blnSpinL == true){
     dblangle -= 1;
   document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.transform = "rotate(" + dblangle + "deg)";
   dblMathAngle++;
   if (dblMathAngle == 360)
   dblMathAngle = 0;
  }
}


function movePlayer() {
  var dblSpeedPerAngle = 0.0;
  var dblNewAngle = 0.0;

if (dblMathAngle >= 0 && dblMathAngle <= 90) {  // First Quad
dblNewAngle = 90 - dblMathAngle;
dblSpeedPerAngle = dblSpeed / 90;
dblLeftSpeed = dblSpeedPerAngle * dblNewAngle;
dblTopSpeed = (dblSpeed - dblLeftSpeed) * -1;
}else if (dblMathAngle >= 91 && dblMathAngle <= 180 ){ // Second Quad
dblNewAngle = 90 - dblMathAngle;
dblSpeedPerAngle = dblSpeed / 90;
dblLeftSpeed = dblSpeedPerAngle * dblNewAngle;
dblTopSpeed = (dblSpeed + dblLeftSpeed) * -1;
}else if (dblMathAngle >= 181 && dblMathAngle <= 270){ // Third Quad
dblNewAngle = 270 - dblMathAngle;
dblSpeedPerAngle = dblSpeed / 90;
dblLeftSpeed = dblSpeedPerAngle * dblNewAngle * -1;
dblTopSpeed = (dblSpeed + dblLeftSpeed);
}else{ // Forth Quad
dblNewAngle = 270 - dblMathAngle;
dblSpeedPerAngle = dblSpeed / 90;
dblLeftSpeed = dblSpeedPerAngle * dblNewAngle  * -1 ;
dblTopSpeed = (dblSpeed - dblLeftSpeed);

}

//console.log(dblplayerleft);
dblplayerleft +=  dblLeftSpeed/2;
dblplayertop += dblTopSpeed/2;
  document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.top = dblplayertop + "px";
  document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.left = dblplayerleft + "px";


}
////////////////////////////////////////



}
function mouseDownU(){
  if(blnPlayerMove == true){
blnGoForward = true;
dblSpeed = 5;
  }

}

function mouseDownD(){
  if (blnPlayerMove == true){
    blnGoBack = true;
dblSpeed = -5;
  }

}

function mouseDownR() {
 blnSpinR = true;
}

function mouseDownL() {
  blnSpinL = true;
}

function mouseUpU(){
blnGoForward = false;
dblSpeed = 0;
blnPlayerMove = true;
}
function mouseUpD(){
blnGoBack = false;
dblSpeed = 0;
blnPlayerMove = true;
}
function mouseUpR() {
 blnSpinR = false;
} 

function mouseUpL() {
 blnSpinL = false;
}
unction ObjectCollisionFunction(){

  if ((ObjectBounds(picWall1,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall2,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall3,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall4,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall5,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall6,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall7,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall8,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall9,picPlayer) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picWall10,picPlayer) == true)){
    dblplayerleft += (dblLeftSpeed * -1) ;
    dblplayertop += (dblTopSpeed * -1);

    document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.top = dblplayertop + "px";
    document.getElementById("PlayerTank").style.left = dblplayerleft + "px";

    dblLeftSpeed = 0.0;
    dblTopSpeed = 0.0;


    blnPlayerMove = false;
  }
  if (blnEnd == false){
  if ((ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile1) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile2) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile3) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile4) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile5) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile6) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile7) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile8) == true)||(ObjectBounds(picPlayer,picMissile9) == true)){
    blnEnd = true;
    alert("Your Score was " + intTime );
    alert("please refresh the page to restart the game");

  }
  }

}
function Timer(){
intTime += 1;
}



function ObjectBounds( object1, object2){
  var blncheck = false;
const style1 = getComputedStyle(object1)
const style2 = getComputedStyle(object2)
const object1Top = parseInt(style1.top)
const object1Left = parseInt(style1.left)
const object1Height = parseInt(style1.height)
const object1Width = parseInt(style1.width)
const object2Top = parseInt(style2.top)
const object2Left = parseInt(style2.left)
const object2Height = parseInt(style2.height)
const object2Width = parseInt(style2.width)

    for (intCounter1 = 0; intCounter1 < object2Height; intCounter1++){
      for(intCounter2 = 0; intCounter2 < object2Width; intCounter2++){
        if (((intCounter1 + object2Top) >=   object1Top) && (intCounter1 + object2Top) <= (object1Height + object1Top) && ((intCounter2 + object2Left) >= object1Left && (intCounter2 + object2Left) <= object1Width + object1Left)){

           blncheck = true;

           }


      }
    }
return blncheck;
}
function MissileMoveFunction(){
MissileMovement(picMissile1);
MissileMovement(picMissile2);
MissileMovement(picMissile3);
MissileMovement(picMissile4);
MissileMovement(picMissile5);
MissileMovement(picMissile6);
MissileMovement(picMissile7);
MissileMovement(picMissile8);
MissileMovement(picMissile9);

}


function MissileMovement(object1){
  const style1 = getComputedStyle(object1);
var num = parseInt(style1.top) - 3;
var num2 = parseInt(style1.left) + 50;
object1.style.top = num + "px";
if (ObjectBounds(picWall1,object1) == true){
  object1.style.top = 910 + "px";
  object1.style.left = num2 + "px";
}
if (ObjectBounds(picWall4,object1) == true){
  object1.style.left = 50 + "px";
}
}
```

I expect the HTML code to call the javascript and call an alert box, but it does not call the javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Make sure the script is being requested and gets a 200 OK response containing the expected data.

Comment: Is the `HTML` file and the `JavaScript` file in the same directory ?

Comment: Read this tutorial [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) and learn how to find files locations.

Comment: I read the tutorial and javascript is in the same folder as the HTML. I also tried to connect it to other javascript files and it worked with those. I think something inside the javascript file is preventing it from connecting, but it does not cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking through my code and tring to follow it as the computer would and I found on line 126 there was an extra }. I don't know why I did not get an error because I think that would cause an unexpected token error as it has before. Thank you to everyone who tried to help me with my code.

Comment: Also : "unction ObjectCollisionFunction() {"

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your script tag is not correctly referencing the Javascript file if you do not receive the alerts when you load the page. If both files are in the same directory level, try using the below:

`<script src="./MissileSurvivalScript.js" type="text/javascript></script>`

Comment: There is no `base` in the HTML, so adding `./` will make no difference.

Comment: Adding `type="text/javascript` is (a) actively harmful because you forgot the `"`, (b) pointless because browsers treat scripts as JS by default, (c) risky (because a typo there can break it, see (a)) and (d) recommended against by the HTML specification. So don't do that.